# How to detect if number of associated objects change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  after_save :do_something, if: -> (post) { [ something like post.comments.count.changed? ] }
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

How to execute do_something if number of comments change ?

I want to execute do_something if I detect more than 3 changes by example : 2 comments added, 2 deleted.

Comment: What's the purpose of `do_something` method?

Comment: Why not trigger from `Comment`'s `after_create` callback instead?